# How to download high chart data in java?

Tags: java, highcharts, web-scraping

I'd like to download the underlying data that is used for a high chart on a given website. The main use case is that I would like to perform my own custom analysis on the graph data.

Is there some sort of webscraping api that I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fullfill your task you must parse data from html page, if site have some api to get data prefer to use this way. Assume your site not have api to get data. 
For parsing data from pages you need to use library https://jsoup.org/ or analogue from this list https://mvnrepository.com/open-source/html-parsers after that you must analize data what you want to parse and create data classes like `Chart` (maybe you also need class`Row` etc.) with fields according to data in chart on html page, something like this (very simple):

```
 class Chart {
        List<Row> chartRows;

        Chart(List<Row> rows) {
          chartRows = rows;
        }
    }
```

Do this to any data you want to parse. Jsoup library have convinient facility not only parse pages but download them (all examples present in https://jsoup.org/) but i reccomend don't mix code responsible to download pages with code to parse, decouple them. After you populate your `Chart` class with data do what you want with them.